# Mapping a working substitute command to a shortcut via vimrc

Tags: vim

The following substitute command works fine on the command line:

`:s/\vlabel\{(\w|:)+}/nonumber`

It searches for `label{eq:xyz123}` and replaces its occurence on the current line line with `nonumber`.

I would like to map this to a command via vimrc. I tried:

`nnoremap <leader>nn :s/\vlabel\{(\w|:)+}/nonumber<CR>`

but this gives the error:

`E492: Not an editor command: :)+}/nonumber<CR>`

What is the right way to effect this mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
nnoremap <leader>nn :s/\vlabel\{(\w<bar>:)+}/nonumber<CR>
```

Note the use of `<bar>` instead of `|`. The error occurs because `|` is interpreted as a delimiter of commands; i.e., Vim is interpreting your command as if there were two separate lines:

```
nnoremap <leader>nn :s/\vlabel\{(\w
:)+}/nonumber<CR>
```

For more, you can read `:help map-bar`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks! Is there a way to have this operate on each line of a visual selection? I selected a set of lines visually and tried `\nn` but that does not work as expected. If that is a separate question in itself, let me know and I will not pursue it here.

Comment: Ah, don't bother. Got that with vnoremap in place of nnoremap.